# Android intent, Same activity is repeating

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

Hi I am doing android code in Kotlin first time, when I tried to use Intent instead of going to the next page tghe same activity is repeating. I am giving my activity code here

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        // get reference to button
        val btnStart = findViewById<Button>(R.id.start_button)
        // set on-click listener
        btnStart.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "You clicked me.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val intent = Intent(this, QuestionActivity::class.java).apply {
            }
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No need of .apply{ } here but same above code works fine for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val intent = Intent(this, QuestionActivity::class.java).apply {
            }
            startActivity(intent)
```

to

```
val intent = Intent(this, QuestionActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

startActivity(Intent(this, QuestionActivity::class.java))

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Thanks Bro. I will consider it next time..